# JOIN for specific row number

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

I am using Postgres and would like to do a table join on a specific row number.

I have the following:

```
LEFT JOIN trip_approver_snapshot tas ON trip.trip_id=tas.trip_id 
and select * from (select row_number() over(order by id) as tas_row_num from trip_approver_snapshot) tasn where tasn.tas_row_num = 1
```

In order to try get just the first row. (I will also need to get row 2 and row 3, but first just want to get row 1 working).

However, the above query gives the following error:

> SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "select"   Position:
> 7102

[image]

More info:

If I run the following:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  (
    select 
      row_number() over(
        order by 
          id
      ) as tas_row_num 
    from 
      trip_approver_snapshot
  ) tasn 
where 
  tasn.tas_row_num = 1
```

[image]

Comment: You cannot apply `SELECT` within a `JOIN` clause. Could you provide the complete query ? and also add some simple data and the expected output

Comment: [Here's something in case you're trying to paginate](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/).

Comment: Just select the other columns also `select * from (select  *, row_number() ....`

Comment: @Charlieface That on its own changes nothing about the syntax error shown by OP. It’s reasonable to suspect there are plenty of duplicate or similar threads but I don't think that particular one is a good candidate to link this one to; the thread you picked is for Microsoft SQL Server, it’s unrelated to pagination and doesn’t discuss attempting that as a part of a chain of joins.

Comment: @Zegarek I was trying to say that the second query would have worked, it was just missing the `*`. The real answer isn't to try and fix the first query, it's to rewrite it completely. I've changed the duplicate link to a better one for Postgres.

Comment: @Charlieface That's clear and I agree, it would be best to see the full context of the task and work out a solution from the ground up. Thing is, OP seems to be interested not just in fixing the whole thing (which they don't seem to be able to share) but primarily in learning how to do a certain thing, in that specific context - that's pagination applied in the `join` list. The changed link addresses one of three points I raised (this was meant to be a vote to reopen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to [paginate](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/). The idea you showed is syntactically wrong but even if you fix that, it's logic is still not quite right.

If your goal was to only use the first row from `trip_approver_snapshot`, you could replace the table with a [`lateral` subquery](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) taking only that one row from it:

```sql
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT * FROM rip_approver_snapshot AS tas
                   WHERE trip.trip_id=tas.trip_id
                   ORDER BY tas.id LIMIT 1 OFFSET 0) tas 
     ON TRUE
```

To get only the 2nd row, you just increase `OFFSET` to `1`. To get the 3rd bump it up to 2, and so on. The [post I linked](https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/) discusses [`LIMIT`/`OFFSET`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html)-based pagination as an intuitive but not really optimal method.

There are better ways to build this `join` but best choice depends on your table structure, indexes and what your full query is aimed to achieve, none of which you disclosed.

---

Right now, in the first query you posted, if you fetched stuff from `trip_approver_snapshot`, it had no way to correlate to its numbered copy in the subquery. You

1. Took rows from `trip_approver_snapshot`
2. Wiped their contents (you didn't select anything except a `row_number()`)
3. Asked for all of that (`select *`)
4. Discarded all of that except the one with number `1`.

All of that as a `join` condition. A `(select 1)` would save you some trouble of getting a single row with a `1` in it.